# Cant write data to firebase database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send test data to my firebase database. In android studio I chose Tools > Firebase > Assistant FB > Realtime Database > Connect your app to Firebase(Connected) > Add the realtime database to your app(dependencies set up correctly).

Then I add sample code in my activity:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

I set the rules in firebase:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But the data does not add to the realtime database. Maybe I need some permission? In logcat AS nothing error

**UPD:**

not add data

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("message").setValue("Hello, World!");
```

not add data too

```
Message mess = new Message("hello");
        mDatabase.child("message").setValue(mess);
```

class Message

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Message {

    public String mes;

    public Message(){}

    public Message(String mes) {this.mes = mes;}

}
```

Comment: do you have a root node in the firebase database console? Did you click get started in the firebase database console?

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks for your comment. Yes, i have [http://take.ms/nCFEN](http://take.ms/nCFEN)

Comment: add data in the firebase console by clicking `+` and then adding name and value does it work?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, data is add when i press `+`. Then i check, and i add data from hurl.it [http://take.ms/nzHKx](http://take.ms/nzHKx) I cant understand why from android app data not add

Comment: clean>build the project and add this under onCreate   private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("message").setValue("Hello, World!");. Debug the app on a device and you should get `message:hello`, World under root node

Comment: @PeterHaddad This did not work for me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check and ensures your are submitting data to firebase else firebase will not write to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours. Please go again to Tools -> Firebase -> Realtime Database -> and make sure that you Firebase is connected and Realtime Database is set up. Hope it helps.)